# Node JS sockets, localhost working, 127.0.0.1 not working

Tags: node.js, http, sockets, server, localhost

For some reason, localhost:3000 is able to create a socket on my server, but 127.0.0.1:3000 is not. 127.0.0.1:3000 successfully pulls up the content but does not connect to the server, despite the code below :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Here is the error I am getting :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NvqFfaS' 
from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I do not understand why it is treating the 2 differently.

Here is the server.js file that gets run:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express(); 
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));



app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});









console.log("Socket is running"); 

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection',newConnection); 
function newConnection(socket){
    console.log('new connection: '+socket.id);
    socket.on('mouse',mouseMsg);

    function mouseMsg(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('mouse',data);
        //io.sockets.emit('mouse',data);
        console.log(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response on the client?

Comment: Presumably, connecting with localhost:3000 doesn't require CORS because it's the same origin as the client. in other words, your CORS config isn't being reached at all, for socket.io connections because the error message would be different if you were getting a wrong origin value.

Comment: @KevinB the code is in the main server.js file that gets run though

Comment: Right, however, socket.io requests might not be getting routed through that middleware.

Comment: @KevinB I just added the complete server.js code. I can send the client side if you need that too.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing the steps here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can't have multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers. This is what I use:

```js
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': contentType,
    ...(req.headers.origin ? {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '"' + req.headers.origin + '" always'} : {}),
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '"true"',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '"origin,range,hdntl,hdnts,accept-encoding,referer,CMCD-req,CMCD-Object,CMCD-Status,CMCD-Session" always',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '"GET,POST,OPTIONS" always',
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': '"Server,range,Date,hdntl,hdnts,Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Ing,Akamai-Mon-Iucid-Del,Akamai-req-BC,Content-Length,Content-Range,Geo-Info,Quic-Version" always',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0',
}
```

> I do not understand why it is treating the 2 differently.

I've just made an experiment: I emptied `/etc/hosts`, then I put

```
1.1.1.1 localhost
```

into `/etc/hosts`, then `ping localhost` said:

```
64 bytes from localhost (1.1.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=31.2 ms
```

So, for some unknown reason `localhost` is not necessarily `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: From the browser's perspective with regard to CORS, regardless of the IP address `localhost` is directed to, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are two different origins. Editing hosts won't change that.

Comment: *"you can't have multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers"* is correct, but the error says the header is missing, not that this origin isn't allowed. so while i think that change is useful, i don't think it'll solve the problem